# Can I convert .docx Word documents using the DocX .NET Library?

Tags: ms-word, docx

I am currently attempting to convert a couple of .NET desktop applications that I have developed into a web application harnessing AngularJS and RESTful services.

One of the key components of these applications is in their ability to generate Word documents on the fly using a .dotx Word template.  I am currently exploring the possibility of using a third party library called [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/) to generate these Word documents without resorting to using a template.

I guess my question is: Can I use this library to read an existing Word document in .docx format and generate a source code representation of the document?  If this is possible could someone point me in the direction of any code samples that I could use? I have looked around and have been unable to find anything that could help me get started.

Comment: I would appreciate any comments as to why I am being downvoted.  I don't see anything wrong with the question I have just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Generating code representation of the document and using it with DocX seems like a time consuming effort to me. Why not using a template instead and fill it with data at runtime?

I have some experience with [Docentric](http://www.docentric.com), which is 3rd party OpenXML toolkit. It features an Word Add-in for template design and libraries for document generation and manipulation. It took me less then a week to generate pretty complex documents. If I was in your shoes I would definitely try some 3rd party toolkits. They cost money, but save time so do some math and see it they can be useful for you.

Comment: I am currently using templates in an existing application, however I am converting it to an AngularJS web application supported by a REST back end and I would like to generate PDFs instead of Word documents.  My idea is to have an HTML representation of the document and then use a 3rd party application to convert it to a PDF, e.g. `wkhtmltopdf` which is free and as long as it can be used on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read an existing Word document in .docx format with following code

```
DocX document = DocX.Load(filename)
```

While it is impossible to generate a source code representation of a document.